# RTL8188EUS nic not working on kernel > 3.19

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

I have been struggling with this NIC for quite some time, I downloaded the drivers from the [official TP-LINK source](http://www.tp-link.com/ar/download/TL-WN723N.html#Driver), but they say they support kernels only from 2.6-ish up to 3.19, and of course the module won't compile on my 4.8 box (the errors say something among the lines of "not discarding void as it should" on the rtw_debug module). So I read through various posts on the web and found out about [a git repo with the driver for RTL8188EU chipsets](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu), so I downloaded and installed it correctly (following instructions from the git readme [and this forum entry](http://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=11261.0)), now I can see available APs around me but sadly I can't connect to any of them, it just hangs around trying to connect but fails, they also all appear to have 0% signal strength. I think it has to do with the fact that my nic is a RTL8188EUS and the driver module is for 8188EU NICs (despite both being listed as `0bda:8179`), however, I want to know if you had any experience with this model and how did you solve it.

Comment: Don´t you mean *on kernel >3.19*?

Comment: Ugh, yes, that's exactly what I meant, thank you.